# SOCI Code for Stored Procedure Execution for DB2 v10.5

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to execute a stored procedure created and compiled in a DB2 database through the `soci proc.execute() function`. The procedure is compiling without any errors when executed in the database directly using the `CALL PROC_NAME(?)` syntax. The procedure has one out parameter `( CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME(OUT PARAM VARCHAR(10)) )`.

The below code is throwing an error :

```
procedure proc = (CONNECTION::sql->prepare<<"PROC_NAME()",into(out_Param)) ;
proc.execute(true) ;
ERROR : Error while detecting column size SQLMESSAGE: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0101E The statement did not return a result set. SQLSTATE=07005
But the Procedure Executes Suxxessfully in database.

***db2 => CALL PROC_NAME(?) ;
Value of output parameters
Parameter Name : RETVAL
Parameter Value : SUCCESS
Return Status = 0
db2 =>***
```

---

The Below Code Works through soci:

```
string OUT ;
procedure proc = (CONNECTION::sql->prepare<<"CALL PROC_NAME(:out_Param)", use(OUT,"out_Param")) ;
proc.execute(true) ;
```

But I am not able to print the `"out_Param"` variable in the code. the value is null.

I have tried other ways like preparing and executing the statements, but none of them worked for me.

My requirement is I want to execute the procedure though soci in DB2 database and want to copy the out parameter value from the procedure to host variable.

If there is any other way to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: For Thome who did not know, SOCI is an alternative to embedded c code, http://soci.sourceforge.net

Comment: Seems like a soci problem (Error while detecting column size). It is asking for the type of value of the output, but there is no output. Have you created a ticket in github?

Comment: https://github.com/SOCI/soci/search?q=column_size&type=Code